# Проблема с adb shell service call

Tags: android, adb

Есть 3 телефона с android 6.0 на каждом из них вызываю команду: adb shell service call phone 2 s16 "" s16 "99999999999". На sony все работает как надо, начинается вызов и идет звонок, на одном acer ничего не происходит, на другом точно таком же acer все работает.

При выполнении подобной команды:adb shell service call phone 1 s16 "99999999999" которая должна просто набирать номер без вызова все работает на всех телефонах, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Как я понимаю команда эмулирует входящий звонок. Почему именно через adb это делаете? Можно же например через Android Device Monitor

Comment: Команда набирает номер и совершает вызов. Использую adb в своем приложении, которое отправляет разные команды телефону на исполнение. Была необходимость делать это из под командной строки, поэтому выбрал именно adb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и не разобрался, почему команда: `adb shell service call phone 1 s16 "99999999999"` не работает на acer телефонах. Но нашел другую команду, которая делает тоже самое и работает на acer phone. Чуть медленнее выполняется запрос, но разница минимальна. Всем спасибо.

Команда: `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:+6512345678`